# text not showing up over background image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a landing page, and this might sound like a stupid question, but my `<h2>` and `<form>` elements are not showing up anywhere on my page. I have tried everything I can think of and still, nothing. I'm baffled.

The photo I am using for my full screen background image is one off of photoshop with a grey square in the center (which looks like what some people do with z-index). In the background, it is cycling logo's in js as a kind of throwback design.

I am not sure if I am doing something wrong, or if there is something in my css, html, js making it so the text/form is not showing up.

**index.html**

```
 <section id="bg">
        <img src="img/bg.jpg">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12" id="rotating-img-wrapper">
                    <img class="rotating-img" src="img/corona.png">
                    <img class="rotating-img" src="img/mc.png">
                    <img class="rotating-img" src="img/mtv.png">
                    <img class="rotating-img" src="img/op.png">
                    <img class="rotating-img" src="img/supercell.png">
                </div>
            </div> 
            <div class="text">
              <h2>To learn more about our services, drop us a line</h2>
               <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email Address</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Password">
                </div>
              </div>       
            </div>            
    </section>
```

**css**

```
#bg {
  position: fixed; 
  top: -50%; 
  left: -50%; 
  width: 200%; 
  height: 200%;
}
#bg img {
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 
  right: 0; 
  bottom: 0; 
  margin: auto; 
  min-width: 50%;
  min-height: 50%;
}

#rotating-img-wrapper img {
  position: fixed;
  width: 250px;
  height: 750px;
}

.rotating-img {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

h2 {
  color: #000000;
  position: absolute;
}
```

**javascript**

```
$(window).load(function() { 
    var InfiniteRotator =
    {
        init: function()
        {
            //initial fade-in time (in milliseconds)
            var initialFadeIn = 1000;

            //interval between items (in milliseconds)
            var itemInterval = 5000;

            //cross-fades time (in milliseconds)
            var fadeTime = 2500;

            //number of items
            var numberOfItems = $('.rotating-img').length;

            //current item
            var currentItem = 0;

            //show first item
            $('.rotating-img').eq(currentItem).fadeIn(initialFadeIn);

            //loop through the items
            var infiniteLoop = setInterval(function(){
                $('.rotating-img').eq(currentItem).fadeOut(fadeTime);

                if(currentItem == numberOfItems -1){
                    currentItem = 0;
                }else{
                    currentItem++;
                }
                $('.rotating-img').eq(currentItem).fadeIn(fadeTime);

            }, itemInterval);
        }
    };
    InfiniteRotator.init();
});
```

If anyone can see an error(s) in my code that I cannot see, I would love to know. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Everything is in the #bg section, which is way off the page due to the -50% positioning.

Comment: @colonelsanders I had to make that -50% because I was getting a small white border around the image.

Comment: @colonelsanders pointed out the key issue with the code, which I found in my solution posted below.  The small white border is probably due to the default browser style sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have some insight into how you might approach this layout.

I simplified your HTML slightly (removed the form and put in a simple line of text) so
as to concentrate on the various stacking layers due to the fixed and absolutely
positioned elements.

The key is that since your `#bg` element is fixed, it sets the reference point for 
positioning any other positioned child elements, be it fixed or absolute.

In your original post, you set the offsets to be `top: -50%` and `left: -50%`, which
places the origin of the block outside of the visible viewing area.

As a result, `h2` was positioned at the top left corner of `#bg`, hence not visible,
and the `p` text, which is in regular content flow, would also start to the top left
of the container block (`#bg`).

As a start, set the offsets to `top: 0` and `left: 0` with 100% for the width and height,
and then rethink about how to size your images in your image rotator and the background
image.

Now that you see where the elements are, you will make be able to make progress 
with your layout.

```css
body {
  margin: 0; /* get rid of 10px border from default browser style sheet */
}
#bg {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#bg img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  min-width: 50%;
  min-height: 50%;
}
#rotating-img-wrapper img {
  position: fixed;
  width: 250px;
  height: auto;
}
.rotating-img {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
h2 {
  color: #000000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<section id="bg">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12" id="rotating-img-wrapper">
        <img class="rotating-img" src="http://placekitten.com/2000/4000">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="text">
      <h2>To learn more about our services, drop us a line</h2>
      <p>Some other words ...</p>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to actually give me some advice on how I could approach this particular problem a little better. I appreciate the help my friend.

Answer (score 0):

You can use background-image: url(img/bg.jpg); in #bg, instead of adding the image directly and try to add something on it.

Answer (score -1):

In your image CSS, do this in the CSS:

```
z-index:-1000;
```

The z-index controls what elements overlap other elements. The higher the z-index, the more in front an element will be. See if that clears anything up. Otherwise, there is another issue. I am also curious as to why you are using absolute positioning on all those elements.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I tried your suggestion in `div class='text'`, but no luck. And they're `position:absolute;` (for the images) so it's similar to the one before it. Or at least that's how I understood `position:absolute;`

Comment: As said above, and it also just came to me, in CSS do this:

Answer (score -1):

In CSS try this code:

```
#bg {
    background-image:url('img/bg.jpg');
}
```

And then remove the  tag from the HTML page. I would also take a look at simplifying your code since you seem to have a ton of divs all wrapped within each other. Perhaps consider using a table if it suits your needs.